# Swift and web service with SOAP

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, soap

I'm just starting with swift to program for IOS. I'm already did an app for Android that consume some web services. I need to do the same app, but now for IOS.
I already could call the web service correctly and print the response, but I need to access to the properties that the web service return. Ahh, I have various web service and some of them return string arrays. This is the code I'm using to call the services

```
var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var err: NSError?
    var user = nameTextField.text
    var pass = passTextField.text
    lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    lobj_Request.addValue(hostString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    lobj_Request.addValue("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    lobj_Request.addValue(String(soapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue(SOAP_ACTION, forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)")

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: " + error!.description)
        }

    })
    task.resume()
```

I know the properties are in data (obviously), but I don't know how to access to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very good library to solve this issue. It's call SWXMLHash.
https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash
I only did this:

```
var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString)!)
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var err: NSError?
var user = nameTextField.text
var pass = passTextField.text
lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
lobj_Request.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
lobj_Request.addValue(hostString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
lobj_Request.addValue("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
lobj_Request.addValue(String(soapMessage.characters.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
lobj_Request.addValue(SOAP_ACTION, forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Body: \(strData)")

    var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)

    var propertyIwant = xml["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["SoapResponse"]["SomeField"]["propertyIwant"].element?.text

    if error != nil
    {
        print("Error: " + error!.description)
    }

})
task.resume()
```

Comment: Glad SWXMLHash was able to help out - I actually originally wrote it because I had to deal with parsing SOAP in an iOS app!

Answer (score 0):

If your web service returns the string with JSON, you'll need to parse it.
Please consider : 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-parse-json-using-nsjsonserialization

And if it's XML string : 
http://dubinski.org/wpis/easy-xml-parsing-in-swift/

I meant the "strData".

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Swift 2.0. But I found a very good library.